# How to add student to a list present in another file?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add Talha Ali to students list. i have made a function but don't know what to return to add the student.

```
Students=[("Abdul Saboor , 14007"), ("Anila Jaffer , 14014")]

def add_student(Studentname,Roll ):
'''(Student name,Roll Number) -> Student name,Roll Number
Adds student to the Students list

>>> add_student(Talha Ali,Bsee 13050)
Talha Ali , Bsee 13050
'''
return
```

Comment: If this function adds a single name to a specific list outside its scope, then it wouldn't make any sense for it to return anything. It would make more sense to return a list of student names if you passed in the file to read from, and the function creates a list of student names that it returns

Answer (score 0):

You can use the append method:

```
def add_student (studentname, roll):
   s = (studentname,roll)
   students.append(s)
   return students
```

Check the following link for more information on data structures:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: it gives the error that name talha ali is not defined.

Comment: try "talha ali" with the double quotes at the beginning and at the end